# Django RestFramework Error Associate with DateTimeField Serializer on POST Request

Tags: python, json, django, serialization

Based on the below Serializer, Mixin, and View, I'm able to successfully retrieve JSON data via GET request (see below), but I'm receiving `"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'request'"` when trying to perform a JSON POST via Django Restframework and I can't figure out why.  Please help.  I also added the TransactionDateTime model and JSON POST request that is giving me the error.  I'm using Postman to send the request. Thanks in advance. My guess is that my issue is with serializers.DateTimeField, because I successfully insert data via the Django shell using the below

```
my_date = datetime.strptime('2015-01-28 05:30:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Please see the below serializer, successful JSON that was returned via GET Request, Mixin, View, Model and POSt JSON Request that is generating the error.

serializer

```
class SimpleSerializer4(BulkSerializerMixin, ModelSerializer):

    user = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    start_dt = serializers.DateTimeField(format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'])   

    def get_user(self, obj):
        test_me = self.context.get('request')
        return test_me


    class Meta(object):
        model = TransactionDateTime
        list_serializer_class = BulkListSerializer
        fields = ('pk','start_dt', 'user')
```

Successful JSON data via GET Request

```
 [
  {
   "pk": 1,
   "start_dt": "2015-01-28 03:00:00",
   "user": "cdoe"
  },
  {
   "pk": 2,
   "start_dt": "2015-01-28 05:30:00",
   "user": "cdoe"
  }
 ]
```

Views and Mixin

```
class DateTimeMixin(object):
    serializer_class = SimpleSerializer4
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)


class DateTimeViewSet(DateTimeMixin, generics.BulkModelViewSet):

    def get_queryset(self):

        num = self.kwargs['dt_rm']
        num2 = self.kwargs['id']

        r1 = Room.objects.get(id = num)

        s1 = Schedule.objects.get(pk=num2)
        u= self.request.user.pk
        usr = User.objects.get(pk=u)

        if(s1.user.username == usr.username):
            queryset = r1.transactiondatetime_set.all()
            return queryset
        else: raise Http404("User does not exist")



    def get_serializer_context(self):

        num = self.kwargs['id']
        s1 = Schedule.objects.get(pk=num)
        var = s1.user.username
        context = super(DateTimeViewSet, self).get_serializer_context()
        return {'request' : var}
```

TransactionDateTime model

```
 class TransactionDateTime(models.Model):
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    start_dt = models.DateTimeField('start_dateTime')
    end_dt = models.DateTimeField('end_dateTime', blank=True, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.start_dt)
```

JSON POST request that is giving me the error

```
[
  {
    "start_dt": "2015-01-28 03:00:00"

  },
  {
    "start_dt": "2015-01-28 02:00:00"

  }

]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

I.e try not to override the **request** keywork in **context** and return the whole context

In **DateTimeViewSet**

```
def get_serializer_context(self): 
    num = self.kwargs['id'] 
    s1 = Schedule.objects.get(pk=num) 
    var = s1.user.username 
    context = super(DateTimeViewSet, self).get_serializer_context() 
    context['user'] = var
    return context
```

In **SimpleSerializer4**

```
def get_user(self, obj): 
    test_me = self.context.get('user') 
    return test_me
```